# How to use multiple values in sass maps with an each function inside a mixin

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have the following sass map which has multiple values:

```
$map: (key: (value1, value2));
```

Using a standard each function like the below works fine:

```
@each $key, $value1, $value2 in $map {
    // Do whatever here
}
```

But if I try to use the same sort of each function inside a mixin passing the mixin the map, the each function doesn't work with the below:

```
@mixin my-mixin($map) {

    @each $key, $value1, $value2 in $map {
        // Do whatever here
    }       

}
```

How can I use an each function inside a mixin with a map that has multiple values per key?

You can see exactly what I am trying to do with the below, I've trying to make a mixin which outputs a property using a modular scale. There are two module scales used, a default one for small screens (mobile first) and a larger one for larger screens:

```
// Output responsive modular properties
@mixin rms-value($properties) {

    @each $property-name, $property-ms, $property-ms2 in $properties {

        $rem-value: ms($property-ms);
        $px-value: rem-to-pixels($rem-value);
        #{$property-name}: $px-value;
        #{$property-name}: $rem-value;


    }

    // Secondary modular scale used for larger screens  
    @include breakpoint($breakpoint-medium) {

        @each $property-name, $property-ms2 in $properties {

            $rem-value: ms($property-ms2, 1rem, $ms-ratio-large);
            $px-value: rem-to-pixels($rem-value);
            #{$property-name}: $px-value;
            #{$property-name}: $rem-value;

        }

    }

}
```

This could then be used to output a margin-bottom and padding-top for example:

```
$properties: (
    padding-top: (1, 2),
    margin-bottom: (2, 3),
 );

p {
    @include rms-value($properties);
}
```

This was working fine when I was using just a single value per map key

Comment: You are trying to include a mixin inside a mixin. Would you like to add also the breakpoint mixin. I think you probably wanted to to set a mixin inside a mixin which is invalid and not to include it.

Comment: The breakpoint mixin is using:https://github.com/at-import/breakpoint this whole thing worked fine when I only had one value per map key so i don't see the issue with a mixin in a mixin

Comment: You need to provide the smallest amount of code that this will compile as intended (variables, mixins, functions, etc.).  If the breakpoint mixin is not related to the problem, then it shouldn't be part of the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is that you are trying to pass as an argument the map variable. You should try to set inside the mixin your map variable and set as an argument probably the needed key like this:

```
@mixin my-mixin($key) {

  $map: (
    key1: (red, blue),
    key2: black
  );

  @each $key, $value in $map {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

An example without a function:

```
 @mixin my-mixin($key) {

  $map: (
    key1: 10px,
    key2: 10em
  );

  font-size: map-get($map, $key);
}

div {
  @include my-mixin(key2);
}
```

An example here: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9e3741bfbddf1260500f

Comment: I've updated my original post to show exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks